# Improve performance of Array ordering by IDs

Tags: swift, algorithm, core-data, complexity-theory, lookup

I have a function:

```swift
func findExistingModels(ids: [String]) throws -> [Model?] {
    let models: [Model] = try getModelsFromCache(ids: ids)
    // ???
}
```

As you can see, it calls `getModelsFromCache` which roughly looks like this:

```swift
class Model: NSManagedObject {
    let id: String
}

func getModelsFromCache(ids: [String]) throw -> [Model] {
    let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<Model>(entityName: "Model")
    fetchRequest.fetchLimit = ids.count
    fetchRequest.predicate =  NSPredicate(format: "%K IN %@", argumentArray: ["id", identifiers])

    // some CoreData code, like performAndWait
    // Just ignore all the CoreData concurrency aspects

    return models
}
```

As you can see, `getModelsFromCache` returns and array of `Model` which will contain anywhere from `0` to `ids.count` amount of `Model` objects, depending on their existence in the storage.

What I need `findExistingModels` to do is:

```swift
func findExistingModels(ids: [String]) throws -> [Model?] {
    let models: [Model] = try getModelsFromCache(ids: ids)

    return ids.map { id in
        if let model = models.first(where: { model in
            model.id == id
        }) {
            return model
        }
        return nil
    }
}
```

Put in words, I need to map the `ids` to their corresponding `Model`s with the goal of preserving the sorting based on the incoming `ids`, and also, I need to place `nil`s corresponding to the `ids` for which the `Model`s haven't been found.

This algorithm that I wrote, with `first` search, it works, but it's not sound from asymptotic complexity perspective. At worst, this function would produce the complexity of `O(pow(ids.count, 2))`

My question is:

- what is the more effective algorithm for this kind of compartmentalizing?
- does CoreData NSPredicate with `IN` preserve the order of appearing keys after FetchRequest - i.e. can I assume that for ids `["1", "2", "3"]` the array that will be returned from `NSManagedObjectContext.fetch` will be in order of `1, 2, 3` in terms of the ids of the returned objects - and maybe we can build an effective algorithm around that?

I haven't tried yet, but I have a couple of ideas/suggestions:

### Drain Pool

- Turn the `models` array into a slice
- look up via `firstIndex`
- retrieve the item via `index`
- delete the item from `models` so that next time, for next id, we won't search over it

Example:

```
var models = ArraySlice(getCache())
var results = [Model?](repeating: nil, count: ids.count)

ids.enumerated().forEach { index, id in
    if let modelIndex = models.firstIndex(where: { model in
        model.id == id
    }) {
        let model = models[modelIndex]
        models.remove(at: modelIndex)
        results[index] = model
    }
}

return results
```

Do you think this is a good idea? Can't quite calculate the complexity in my head...

### Set

- make `Model` hashable, where hash is calculated as `id`, literally just the value of it
- turn array into set
- look up the value by the hash...? somehow?

Maybe this will be faster?

Comment: One detail, sql query results are unordered unless you supply a sort order so in Core Data lingo, your fetch request will need sort descriptors to retrieve the objects in a specific order.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson exactly what I needed to hear - although, do you think I could write a sort descriptor that will tell CoreData to order objects into a specific order of ids in particular?

Comment: Not sure if it can be done using sort descriptors if you don’t want them sorted in a natural order.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson me too! Good, let's put a pin on it, core data sorting is not an option nor a helper.

Comment: Why not just make a dictionary keyed by the IDs? `let modelsById = Dictionary(uniqueKeysWithValues: models.lazy.map { (key: $0.id, value: $0.value } )`

Comment: I think Alexander's answer is the best option here

Comment: ugh @Alexander well, alright, so I've got this dictionary - but it still needs to be converted into an array with all the items in the correct places corresponding to `ids` array - I don't feel like dictionary can help with that... Or you suggest ditch the array altogether?

Comment: @IsaaсWeisberg Then you just map over your IDs (`let models = ids.map { modelsById[$0] }`), and transform each id into its full model by using the dictionary as a lookup table. Crucially, the dictionary's lookups are O(1), so the  whole process ends up `O(ids.count)` rather than `O(id.count^2)` (as in the linear-seaching case)

Comment: @Alexander ohhh wow great idea - very cool. Expect, I have a question - you didn't count in the creation of the dictionary itself... But let me guess, with it it will be... oh my god - `O(id.count*2)`. We access each element in models once and then look up each id in constant time once... Dictionary truly IS a good solution, holy cow!

Comment: @Alexander would you like to retype this as an answer, not a comment? I would gladly accept it as the correct one

Comment: @Alexander also - in your code, you spicifically used `lazy` in `models.lazy.map` - but just so we're on the same page, it doesn't actually change anything, right? We've got only one single operation in this transformation chain, so might as well not use `lazy`, right?

Comment: Sure I’ll type it up later. It is O(ids.count*2), which is actually equivalent to O(ids.count). The `lazy` is an added touch to remove the allocation of the intermediate array allocated for the result of `map`. Though it encurs a closure allocation instead, so it’ll only really help for large inputs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a dictionary, as per @Alexander comments.